# FastAPI Security OAuthPassword2Bearer and Token management not working properly

Tags: python, security, oauth-2.0, jwt, fastapi

using Python 3.9 I tried to follow FastAPI tutorial on security but I cannot manage to show the **authorize** button neither the **lock** near the paths.

In my code (that I cannot show entirely for security purposes) I did everything that appeared in the docs:

```
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="users/login")

@app.post("/users/login")
async def logIn(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    token = management.login(form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if token == False:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Incorrect username or password")
    else:
        return token

#Fake path for privacy reasons
@app.get("/fake/path")
async def read_item(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]):
  return True
```

Yet the **Swagger** do not appear like this

Docs example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/awxQU.png

but instead looks like

My swagger : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y66Rd.png

Why is this happening?

PS: i also tried like this `async def logIn(form_data: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()])` but I got `fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that typing.Annotated[fastapi.security.oauth2.OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends(NoneType)] is a valid pydantic field type`

Answer (score 0):

```py
OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()
```

depends on what? you need to pass a validation function

Comment: In the docs is written: 
```
@app.post("/token")
async def login(form_data: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()]):
```
so I don't know really